# Executable jar file from Maven with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

Maven jar plugin - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from Intellij jar file

I am trying to jar a class from a maven project but getting class not found error.

I have added this to the pom file

```
           <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>training.avro.KafkaAvroJavaProducerV1Demo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I do a maven install and then run

```
java -jar target/kafka-avro-v1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Which is the name of my project, this main class runs fine when i run from intellij.

But then I get this error running from the jar

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: It actually did, I had looked at that before and was not able to get their solution working but tried again and was successful. Copy a version of the accepted answer here if you like and I will accept

Comment: Glad I could help. Just close this question.